# autocomplete jquery in jsp and servlets

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery for autocomplete in search bar; it works in the beginning but once the control is transferred to servlet and then redirected back to the same JSP page the jQuery autocomplete doesn't work; please guide me. PFB the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>   
        <script >

            /*Invoking the jQuery, this gets invoked in the beginning and autosuggestions are shown in the textbox , but once the controlled is transferred to servlet("Here, Connector class") and then redirected back from there to this page the autocomplete jquery doesn't work*/

            jQuery(function(){
                $("#search").autocomplete("Autofill.jsp");
            });

</head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Connector" >
            <input type="text" id="search" ><input type="submit" value=" " class="tfbutton4">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the autocomplete must again be re-initialized. But I am not sure as you have not added any codes.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Added the code as asked by you,Please have a look

Comment: Your missing a script tag

Answer (score 0):

I this below example helps you for auto complete tag in jsp servlet using jquery

jsp look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>jQuery Autocomplete</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<STYLE TYPE="text/css" media="all">
.ui-autocomplete { 
    position: absolute; 
    cursor: default; 
    height: 200px; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    overflow-x: hidden;}
</STYLE>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autoText").autocomplete({
        width: 300,
        max: 10,
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
        cacheLength: 1,
        scroll: true,
        highlight: false,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/JSON/AjaxRequest",
                dataType: "json",
                data: request,
                success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log( data);
                    var items = data;
                    response(items);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     console.log( textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
 
    });
});
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jQuery Autocomplete Example</h1>
    <p>In this example we will have an input box that will provide
        suggestions using autocomplete( url or data, options ) and Ajax
        request.</p>
    <form name="as400samplecode" action="" method="get">
 
        <table>
 
            <tr>
                <td><input id="autoText" maxlength="20" />
                </td>
            </tr>
 
        </table>
 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and your controller

```
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

 public class AjaxRequest extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
      "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
      "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
      "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
      "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
      "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
      "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
      "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
      "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
      "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
      "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
      "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
      "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
      "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
      "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
      "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
      "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
      "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
      "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
      "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
      "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
      "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
      "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
      "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
      "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
      "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
      "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
      "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
      "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
      "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
      "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
      "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
      "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
      "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
      "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
      "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
      "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
      "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
      "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
      "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
    };


public AjaxRequest() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

    JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();

    String query = request.getParameter("term");
    System.out.println(query);
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    for(int i=0; i<COUNTRIES.length; i++) {
        String country = COUNTRIES[i].toLowerCase();
        if(country.startsWith(query)) {
            arrayObj.add(COUNTRIES[i]);
        }
    }

    out.println(arrayObj.toString());
    out.close();

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Do something       
}
```

}

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/jquery-autocomplete-ajax-json-example.html